# adding items to a radlistbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to add items from FileInfo into my RadListBox although I am not able to, I tried casting the file into a RadListBoxItem object, but I get the error that it can not convert a string to a radlistboxitem. Can someone shed a little light? thanks.

```
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(fp));
                lb_Files.Items.Clear();
                foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                {
                    RadListBoxItem rlb = new RadListBoxItem();
                    rlb = (RadListBoxItem)file.ToString();
                    //radListBox
                    lb_Files.Items.Add(rlb.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: What's the code that you had before trying to cast, and what error were you getting?

Comment: lb_Files.Items.Add(file.ToString());
Got the same error when I tried to bind directly

Comment: it was a generic, has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetFullPath(fp));
lb_Files.Items.Clear();
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
{
   lb_Files.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem(file.ToString(), file.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot cast a `String` object into a `RadListBoxItem`, you must create a `RadListBoxItem` using that string as your Value and Text properties:

So replace this:

```
 RadListBoxItem rlb = new RadListBoxItem();
 rlb = (RadListBoxItem)file.ToString();
 //radListBox
 lb_Files.Items.Add(rlb.ToString());
```

With this:

```
lb_Files.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem
{
     Value = file.ToString(),
     Text = file.ToString()
});
```